# Why does git pull mess up the soft links and how to fix it

Tags: git

I pulled a remote git repo but the soft links get messed up.
There is a soft link file **abc.xml** under **conf/App1**, which refers to **conf/abc.xml**.
After git pull, the abc.xml under conf/App1 changes its source to **conf/abc.xmlU**.

Remote repo:

```
ls conf/App1
abc.xml -> ../abc.xml
```

Local repo after git pull:

```
ls conf/App1
abc.xml -> ../abc.xmlU
```

The remote repo is correct, and the git pull on other machine is correct. Both machines are Debian Linux, the only difference I am aware of is that the problematic machine does not have default authorization. Every time when git pull, I have to type in my account and password.

I have searched and could not get any clue about what is happening here. Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestions.

Comment: Is the repository accessible to others? If not, I don't think anyone can answer this.

Comment: Has the link changed on the remote? Or does this only happen during the "merge" phase of pull?

Comment: Any way the U comes from your ls command like sometimes you get a `*` for  executable ? Can you try `/bin/ls -l conf/App1` ?

Comment: One possible explanation is that someone made that change on their machine (maybe by accident) and committed it. If that were the case, the git pull on your machine would be doing what it's supposed to. Look at the history of the symlink to see if you can find a commit that changed it in what you just pulled: `git log conf/App1/abc.xml` will list the commits that changed it.

Comment: @torek no, it is not a public accessible repo.

Comment: @knittl  Hey Knittl and joanis, the link stay correct on the remote.   I do agree that it might happen just during "merge", but not clear why and how git could do it.

Comment: @Ôrel  this kind of U change is reflected in git status as tracked changes, so it definitely has nothing to do with ls

Comment: @Peipei but can you verify if it happens during merge? Do you see a diff in the merge commit, aka "evil merge"? Is the corrupted link committed or only modified locally? If you push your broken branch to a remote, and clone fresh, does it show the same problem?

Comment: @knittl  There is no error messages or anything during merge/pull. The corrupted link is not committed and exists only locally.

Comment: @Peipei I wasn't asking about error messages. So you are saying that the link is only broken in your local checkout, but not in your local commits? `git status`/`git diff` show the link as modified? Or has been never committed at all? (in the latter case, Git cannot and will not modify the file).

Comment: @knittl Yes, the link is only broken in my local checkout. This change I have never committed, no one wants to commit a broken link. It never gets into my local commits since every time after pulling the repo, I have to manually delete the file and recreate the correct soft link.

Comment: So it is in fact committed and tracked? To me it still sounds this link got corrupted and committed. Check the history. There must be a reason why Git changes the content of the link. Can you provide a [mre]? Or can you extract the few commits which reproduce this behavior? Without repro, I'm afraid nobody can help.